# how to download zipfile via python through a proxy

Tags: python

I need to download a zipfile through a proxy but i am getting a "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" error.

```
import requests
import zipfile
import io

proxies = {
    'http': 'Proxy server',
}

# Create the session and set the proxies.
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

# Make the HTTP request through the session.
r = s.get('http://bloomberg.bintray.com/BLPAPI-Experimental-Generic/blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1-windows.zip')

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
zip.extractall("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\")
```

Please help thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into what's in `r.content`?

Comment: print(r.encoding), it is ISO-8859-1

Comment: I asked for `r.content` but you gav me `r.encoding`. Your error says r.content does not look like the contents of a zip file so we need to see what's in `r.content`.

Comment: the problem may occur as the url links elsewhere, could that be the problem?

Comment: "url links elsewhere" - do you mean redirects to another URL? Then follow the redirect to get at the actual ZIP contents.

Comment: C:\PROGRAMS\Miniconda3_64\python.exe C:/Users/luahx/PycharmProjects/1/1.py
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">\n<HTML ..... and it goes on and on

Comment: So you're getting an HTML instead of a ZIP file in response to your GET. I suggest you save that HTML to a file then open said file in your browser. You may have been black-listed by the owners of the site. I'm guessing the HTML will have such a message.

Comment: i found the problem, my proxy is not working properly, still being blocked

Comment: Once you get blocked, it would be difficult to get through. They know about those proxy services.